# ASP.NET Custom Validator Error Message: Control referenced by the property cannot be validated

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

I use ASP.NET and have a Button and a CustomValidator, which has to validate
the button.

```
<asp:Button ID="saveButton" runat="server" OnClick="SaveButton_Click" Text="Speichern"
    CausesValidation="true"/>
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="saveCValidator" Display="Static"
    OnServerValidate="EditPriceCValidator_ServerValidate"   
    ControlToValidate="saveButton" ErrorMessage="">
```

When loading the page, I receive the error message:

> "Control 'saveButton' referenced by
>   the ControlToValidate property of
>   'saveCValidator' cannot be validated."

What might be the problem? I searched on the net, but this didn´t help much.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can only use a [CustomValidator against Input controls that accept user input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx):

> Client-side validation enhances the
>   validation process by checking user
>   input before it is sent to the server.

What you want to do is look here at [Button Controls and Validation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx#ButtonControlsAndValidation)

Answer (score 29):

AFAIK, `ControlToValidate` property should point to input control or left blank for the  `CustomValidator` control.

A reference from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controltovalidate.aspx):

> Use the `ControlToValidate` property to
>   specify the input control to validate.
>   This property must be set to the ID of
>   an input control for all validation
>   controls except the `CustomValidator`
>   control, which can be left blank. If
>   you do not specify a valid input
>   control, an exception will be thrown
>   when the page is rendered. The ID must
>   refer to a control within the same
>   container as the validation control.
>   It must be in the same page or user
>   control, or it must be in the same
>   template of a templated control.
>
> The standard controls that can be
>   validated are:
>
> - System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList
> - System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload
> - System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox
> - System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList
> - System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
> - System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputFile
> - System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputPassword
> - System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText
> - System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect
> - System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea