# Invalidate Page via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have a registration form with several validator controls. I am checingk the username availability via
AJAX (using jQuery, NOT an UpdatePanel). If the username is taken, I would like to make the page invalid like the other ASP.NET validators do from my JavaScript function. Is this possible? Examples?

Here is my current functionality:

```
// In head...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%= username.ClientID %>').blur(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: 'MyService.asmx/CheckAvailability',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '{ "username": "' + username + '" }',
            success: function (response) {

                // stuff

                // If username is taken, invalidate

            }, error: function () { /* stuff */ }
        });
    });
});
</script>

// The markup...
<dl><dt>Username</dt>
<dd>
    <asp:textbox id="username" runat="server" />
    <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="usernameRequiredValidator" runat="server"
        controltovalidate="username"
        errormessage="Required"
        display="Dynamic" />
    <span id="avail_response"></span>

<!-- More stuff... -->
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with 'make the page invalid' ?
Or perhaps give an example . .

Comment: When one of your form elements is "invalid", the user can not submit the form. This is automatically handled w/ASP.NET validation controls. I would like to hook this functionality from my AJAX function.

Comment: Instead of invalidating the page, is it enough to invalidate the submit button in the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa479045) provides an in-depth explanation of ASP.Net validation. Scroll down to the paragraph 'The Client-Side API' where it explains that you can set the Page_IsValid variable. Be warned however, there is no guarantee that this API will stay the same in future versions of .NET so check for the existence of Page_IsValid.

EDIT :

Sorry, in my previous comment I was in a bit off a hurry and I just answered your question without looking at the bigger picture. I just reread your question and indeed, it will do nothing because when you the user clicks the submit button, it triggers a revalidation of all validators. Because the textbox username has a value, your requiredvalidator is valid and the form submits.

I think that a better solution in the long run (and one that doesn't directly call javascript functions of .NET) is the following :

1. Add a hidden field
2. Create a requiredfieldvalidator for that hidden
   field
3. Place the requiredfieldvalidator behind the first requiredvalidator and give it the same errormessage as that requiredvalidator
4. Place some value in the hidden field in
   your success function if the
   username is available, in all other
   cases, make the hidden field empty.

It's a bit of a detour but it's future proof & easier than figuring out how to do it with the javascript functions of the .NET validator framework.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I use the Page_IsValid object in my javascript function above?

Comment: In your success callback function, use 'if (typeof Page_IsValid != 'undefined') { Page_IsValid = false; }' I think it should work but I'm not certain (I cannot check at the moment).

Comment: Yea, I tried setting Page_IsValid manually, but it does nothing

Comment: link in Post isn't valid anymore. But the gist is here. :)

Comment: @winner_joiner I fixed the link (& 2 spelling errors). Thanks for informing me.

Comment: @SemVanmeenen I know this post is a little old now but I came up with this exact same work around but it give me this error: `Control 'hidLogin' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'rfHidLogin' cannot be validated.`

Comment: @Fred There is a stackoverflow question with the same eror as you : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637702/asp-net-custom-validator-error-message-control-referenced-by-the-property-canno). One of the anwsers points to a MSDN page ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controltovalidate.aspx)) that explains that the control that you want to validate must be an input field. Is that the case ?

Comment: @SemVanmeenen Thanks for the reply.  Yes that is the case and it makes sense that they have to be input controls.  I just found your post so wondered if there was a way round it. I gave up with that approach in the end.